# Inverse of homogenous function?

Tags: functions

suppose that $\alpha>0$ and $f$ is an invertible function such that $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$. Does this automatically also imply that $f^{-1}(\alpha x)=\alpha f^{-1}(x)$?

I would think yes because $ff^{-1}f(\alpha x)=f(\alpha x)$ but I am not sure this is sufficient to establish the claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does automatically imply that $f^{-1}(\alpha x) = \alpha f^{-1}(x)$.  We can proceed as follows.  Taking the inverse of both side of the original equation gives:
$$f^{-1}(f(\alpha x)) = f^{-1}(\alpha f(x))$$
This evaluates to
$$\alpha x = f^{-1}(\alpha f(x))$$
Now if we define $y = f(x)$, then $x = f^{-1}(y)$ and
$$\alpha f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(\alpha y)$$

Comment: @Chilango  $f$ is given as invertible in the problem.

Comment: yes I overlooked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$ f f^{-1}(\alpha x) = \alpha x $$

$$ f( \alpha f^{-1}(x)) =  \alpha f f^{-1}(x) = \alpha x $$

So if

$$ f^{-1}(\alpha x ) \ne \alpha f^{-1}(x) $$

Then it must be the case that if for some x $u  = f^{-1}(\alpha x ) $   and $ v = \alpha f^{-1}( x )  $ then $$ f(u) = f(v) $$

But that would mean that $f$ isn't invertible since by inverting it you would have some single x, such that $f^{-1}$ maps simultaneously to $u,v$ so if the funciton is invertible then the hypothesis that

$$ f^{-1}(\alpha x ) \ne \alpha f^{-1}(x) $$

cannot be true.